# Определения макросов

Tags: c, динамические-массивы, макросы, макрос

По ходу выполнения лабораторных я наткнулся на задание, где нужно было просто написать программу для подсчета произведения матриц, при этом выделяя память динамически. Звучит довольно просто, но в конце я обнаружил это

> Создать определения макросов, которые подсчитывают, сколько раз в программе произошло использование функций динамического выделения и освобождения памяти, а также объем выделенной и освобожденной памяти.

В методичке ничего не написано кроме пояснений про #define, #if и т.д. Хотелось бы иметь хоть какое-то представление, о чем речь идет)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Похоже, что от вас хотят что-то вроде

```
int total   = 0;
int mallocs = 0;
int frees   = 0;

#define  malloc(s) (mallocs++, total += (s), malloc((s)))
#define  free(s)   (frees++, free((s)))

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char * c = malloc(200);
    char * v = malloc(2000);
    free(c);

    printf("Alloc %d bytes in %d mallocs; frees: %d times\n", total, mallocs,frees);
}
```

Comment: Да, мне кажется, именно это, все понял. Спасибо большое)